# VSCode add icons to Activity Bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I add other extension icons to the `Activity Bar`?
I want to add new custom icon, next to the source control and debug icons.
I read [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view#view-container) but did not understand.
I went to path `C:\Users\Moh\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app` and added this configs to package.json:

```
// etc...
"author": {
  "name": "Microsoft Corporation"
},
"license": "MIT",
"main": "./out/main",

//***************//
// I added following lines:
"contributes": {
  "views": {
    "code-runner": [
      {
        "id": "codeRunner",
        "name": "Code Runner"
      }
    ]
  }
},

// etc...
```

But nothing changed.
Is my chosen path correct?
Is the written configuration correct?

Comment: you need to contribute a ViewContainer (icon in the activity bar) and then contribute a View to this ViewContainer

Comment: Unfortunately, I still did not understand. @rioV8

Comment: have you looked at the example extension for ViewContainer and View

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is added to the `package.json` of your **extension** that you are building.  If you do not know what that means, read the docs on making your first extension.

From the docs, it works:

```
"contributes": {

    "viewsContainers": {

      "activitybar": [

        {
          "id": "package-explorer",        (use this id for the view name below)
          "title": "Package Explorer",
          "icon": "$(heart)"               (using built-in icons, it is this easy)
        }
      ]
    },

    "views": {

      "package-explorer": [                (id from above)

        {
          "id": "package-dependencies",    (viewlets within "PAckage Explorer")
          "name": "Dependencies",
          "type": "tree"
        },
        {
          "id": "package-outline",
          "name": "Outline"
        }
      ]
    }
```

The Activity Bar is one kind of `ViewContainer`.  When you click on the heart icon it opens one view into the Side Bar which has two "viewlets": `Dependencies` and `Outline`.

The built-in icons are discussed here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels but you can use your own as detailed here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#Icon-specifications

WHen you debug your extension you will see the ViewContainer and View contributions in the new vscode window opened to run your extension.

[image: Contributing a ViewCOntainer with Views]

Comment: I went through the sample project and it didn't say how to name the icon, when I put $(heart) in, it showed up on the activity bar instantly - thank you!